# Dynamic ng-init set value in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-init

I want to initiate `ng-init` on page load. I have `task.id` that fetch with `Restangular` and my html is:

```
<textarea rows="5" ng-model="comment.comment_text"></textarea>{{task.id}}
<input type="hidden" ng-model="comment.task_id" ng-init="comment.task_id = $scope.task.id">   
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="create(comment)">Send</button>
```

and angular controller:

```
$scope.create = function(comment) {
     console.log(comment);
};
```

When click on button show result in console:

```
{comment_text: "test", task_id: undefined }
```

But I want to show like this:

```
{comment_text: "test" ,task_id:53}
```

Comment: It should be `ng-init="comment.task_id = task.id"` whithout `$scope`

Comment: I test but doesn't work

Comment: Can your share your full code to give you suggestion

Comment: I solved problem with add `ng-if="task.id!==undefined"`. how to resolve problem without `ng-if`

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
ng-init="comment.task_id = task.id"
```

or you can set from controller

```
$scope.comment.task_id  =$scope.task.id
```

or input value

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="comment.task_id" value="{{task.id}}" />
```

Comment: is there $scope.task.id exist?

Comment: I solved problem with add `ng-if="task.id!==undefined"`. how to resolve problem without `ng-if`

Comment: Three ways i suggested not work? :) Re-check "task" object of $scope is already pushed to the view. Can you show full code in your controller?

Comment: Thanks, but I want implement with ng-init. 2nd solution is true but I want to implement with your 1st solution.

Comment: Nice! :) post a part of your code (enough to run) to http://codepen.io/ then we can find the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<textarea rows="5" ng-model="comment.comment_text"></textarea>{{task.id}}
<input type="hidden" ng-model="comment.task_id" ng-init="comment.task_id = task.id">   
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="create(comment)">Send</button>
```

Comment: I solved problem with add `ng-if="task.id!==undefined"`. how to resolve problem without `ng-if`